# Pandas Dataframe - Group by Col A and sum each groups Col C

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe:

```
COLA    COLB    COLC
a       cfg     100
b       gdd     100     
c       ert     100
d       yrt     100
a       yui     100
d       ouo     100
a       ooo     100
b       qwe     100
```

I want to combine all the items in COLA (groupby?) and then sum their values in COLC and end up with

```
COLA    COLC
a       300
b       200    
c       100
d       200
```

I'm trying:

```
df.groupby('COLA').sum('COLC')
```

Comment: Try: `df.groupby('COLA')['COLC'].sum()`

Comment: Instead try, df.groupby('COLA'). COLC.sum()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GroupBy object supports column indexing in the same way as the DataFrame, and returns a modified GroupBy object

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(path)
df.groupby('COLA')['COLC'].sum()
```